# How do I add text content in a phtml file for translation

Tags: magento, translation

I need to add text content in a **.phtml** file so that I can get it translated for multilingual site.

file location here:
app > design > frontend > default > (my-theme) > template > catalog > category > left_nav.phtml

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Option 1.

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Text here');?>
```

Then add the text in `app/locale/{lang_ISO}/Mage_Catalog.csv`

```
"Text here","Translation here"
```

Option 2.

```
<?php echo $this->__('Text here');?>
```

Then add the text in `app/design/frontend/{interface}/{theme}/locale/{lang_ISO}/translate.csv` like this:

```
"Text here","Translation here"
```

**[EDIT]**
To include links in the text follow this pattern:

```
<?php echo $this->__('some <a href="%s">text here</a>', Mage::getUrl('some/url/here'));
```

Then add to your csv file this line:

```
"some <a href=""%s"">text here</a>","translated <a href=""%s"">text here</a>"
```

`%s` is a placeholder that will be replaced by the second parameter of `__` method.
Also when adding it to the csv file make sure you double the quotes inside the text so `<a href="%s"></a>` should be added to the csv file like `<a href=""%s""></a>`

Comment: Marius, thanks for the help. I preferred Option 2 as my solution.

Comment: What do you mean by 'within the text'? Give an example in your question or add a new one.

Comment: I also needed to add a link within the text and I tried this way which was not helpful:

"lorem ipsum <a href=/link>dolor</a>"

I also added the same text inside the quotes for translation, but this did not work.

Comment: I needed to translate something like this (translation within the quotes): "lorem ipsum dolor <a href=/link>sit</a> amet"